# Can my discord bot grab a random 'Hot' post from a subreddit and link it on command?

Tags: python, reddit, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot that will output copypasta from r/copypasta on command. Instead of manually grabbing copypasta and putting it in a list, i want it to grab a random post from the 'Hot' section of r/copypasta, and reply it when someone uses that command.

I've already tried using IFTTT and webhooks to post things there, but that does it automatically, in a certain channel, and not through my bot.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered using PRAW to get reddit data this you can then use `submission.selfText` to get the data to copypaste and return this using `message.channel.send(submission.selfText)`

Comment: Reddit can be accessed through it's api, [praw](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 2):

```
import praw
from random import randint
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=],
                     client_secret=keys,
                     user_agent=keys,
                     username=keys,
                     password=keys)
postsIds = []
limit = 50

for submission in reddit.subreddit("yoursubreddithere").hot(limit=limit):
    postIds.append(submission.id)

postData = reddit.submission(id=postIds[randint(0,limit)]

print(postData.body) # Your random post data
```

Comment: I will try this out. Thanks